# onClickListener and setOnTouchListener doesn't work in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

In my Android Native code I have written an OnClick Listener for a PopUp I need to display in my onCreate().

I want to write this in native rather than JS.

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pointzipreviewtoolbar,null);
           PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         ViewGroup rootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            popupView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("Popup was Clicked", "I clicked here");
                }
            });
}
}
```

The popup shows, however the onClickListner doesn't get triggered and also the setTouchListener doesn't work either. Am I missing some files??

Comment: Why are you writing native code instead in reactnative ?

Comment: it's for a android sdk native library that i plug into react-native

Comment: So instead of writting code in Native directly. Use `NativeWrapper` then write native code in react native.

Comment: But do you know why onclick and ontouch listner isn't working?

Comment: Simply because there is no layout defined by `setContentView()` method. So there is no view to perform `onClick` or `onTouch`.

Comment: Hi @Mysterious_android did you already resolve your issue? i'm having the same problem.

Comment: hi @Mervzs, yes i got it to work by setting onClick to my child elements inside the parent layout defined in popupView.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the root of the inflated popupView layout to null, which means it might not have correct layoutparams which may affect a touch interaction.

Try rearranging it so you can do this:

```
ViewGroup rootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pointzipreviewtoolbar, rootLayout, false);
```

That way the popupView will inherit the layoutparams from rootLayout, but will still not be attached to that view as the final argument (attachToRoot) is false. See if the onClickListener responds after that.

You've also not used `setContentView(View view)` in onCreate, though maybe that's normal when you inherit from ReactActivity, not sure.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but clicking still doesn't respond :(

Comment: Are you sure the popup is showing? You are just creating a PopupWindow object, but you never call any show methods on it. Also, you have not set your root layout with `setContentView()` in onCreate so I'd be surprised if anything works.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it working by setting onClick to the elements inside my layout.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by setting the pointzipreviewtoolbar layout elements to an onClick.  Which in my case, inside the pointzipreviewtoolbar had an ImageButton called preViewCapture. I then set this to on OnClickListner and it got triggered.

```
  public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                    (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pointzipreviewtoolbar,null);
               PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             ViewGroup rootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        ImageButton image = (ImageButton) popupView.findViewById(R.id.preViewCapture);
                image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.e("Popup was Clicked", "I clicked here");
                    }
                });
    }
    }
```